# How to pass --defsym through the assembly preprocessor?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

This is regarding some arm assembly code that uses a common makefile, but behaves differently for files that need to be preprocessed (xxx.S) and ones that don't (xxx.s).  In my makefile, I have this:

```
ASFLAGS += --defsym BACKDOOR_ADDR=0xC0004000
```

Which seems to work fine with all the legacy assembly files that are not preprocessed (xxx.s).  Now I've got one that does need to be preprocessed (xxx.S), and I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '--defsym'
> ```

I've tried this:

```
ASFLAGS += -Wa,--defsym,BACKDOOR_ADDR=0xC0004000
```

And it works for the xxx.S file, but not for the xxx.s files.  I get the following error from the assembler for xxx.s files:

> Assembler messages:
>   Fatal error: invalid listing option `,'

Is there a way to do this that will work for both cases?

Answer (score 1):

Tweak your makefile so that the "legacy" xxx.s files are also assembled using gcc, then the second option (with -Wa) should work.